# Get a list of elasticsearch stored scripts in elasticsearch 6.4.2

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

I upgraded my ES from `elastic 5.x` to `elasticsearch 6.4.2`, and in this version I can't use scripts as a files but only as [stored scripts](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting-using.html).

I tried to receive all of the stored scripts with this command:

```
curl -XGET <elasticsearch_url>/_scripts
```

But it doesn't work.

There is a way I can get all of the stored scripts that saved in the ES?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve all your stored scripts using the following command

```
curl -XGET '<elasticsearch_url>/_cluster/state/metadata?filter_path=metadata.stored_scripts'
```

Comment: Worked perfectly!

Comment: Moreover, there is an open PR on this issue: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/28368